how to import files from main folder to sub folder?
ps:I am using VS CODE IDE
my project structure is
project
  --src
    old.py
    --components
       new.py

There is a folder named src inside my project folder and inside src there is another folder named components
Now i want to import the old.py from src to new.py in src/components
I have tried the import statements but still getting the error
from src.old import logging
It throws me a error saying

'src' module not found.ModuleNotFoundException


here is the similar question, check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder

You need to follow the module creation documentation
or you can add path to your import serach as this solution suggested
